# good software design patterns, constructor overloading for unit testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am developing a windows form application in c#. When instantiating the form, I initialize a few hardware classes within the constructor. `hardware1, Hardware2, Hardware3` represent the hardware classes that i instantiate in the software.

```
public partial class Form1 {
    Hardware1 a;
    Hardware2 b;
    Hardware3 c;

    public Form1() {
        // initialize hardware1,2 and 3 using native dll calls of a,b and c
    }
```

I want to conduct unit testing for this method within my main form.

```
public int MyMethod(int percent, ref double power) {
    for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if(a.isValid)
            {
                b.DoThing1(percent);
                b.DoThing2(true);
                c.DoSomething1();
                double val = C.DoSomething2();
                if (val != -500)
                {
                    power = val;
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
                return 1;

        }
        return 2; 
    }
```

The difficulty is that a.IsValid is set through some dll calls that i would have to mock. b.DoThing1 and C.DoThing2 also calls some dll function that I would have to mock as well. One possibility is to overload the form method constructor. Then i can mock each classes dll's

```
Form1 (Hardware1 a, Hardware2 b, Hardware3 c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

or should i have interfaces for Hardware1 a, Hardware2 b and Hardware3 c ? I read that its generally better to have interfaces to substitute the concrete classes.

what is good software practice to unit test Form1 myMethod ?

Comment: Here's a question on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com about having separate constructors for unit testing. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/385804/should-my-classes-have-separate-constructors-just-for-unit-testing/385805#385805

Answer (score 5):

The great advantage of using interfaces is that your unit tests can define their own implementation of the interface, which allows your unit tests to execute without external dependencies.

What I would advise you to do is to remove your MyMethod from your form and put it into it's own class.  Generally it's always a good idea to separate business from presentation.

Here's my suggestion :

```
public interface IHardware1 { }
public interface IHardware2 { }
public interface IHardware3 { }

public class Hardware1 : IHardware1 { }
public class Hardware2 : IHardware2 { }
public class Hardware3 : IHardware3 { }


public class MyClass
{
    private IHardware1 _a;
    private IHardware2 _b;
    private IHardware3 _c;

    public MyClass( IHardware1 hardware1, IHardware2 hardware2, IHardware3 hardware3 )
    {
        _a = hardware1;
        _b = hardware2;
        _c = hardware3;
    }

    public int MyMethod( int percent, ref double power )
    {
        ...
            _b.DoThing1( percent );
            _b.DoThing2( true );
            _c.DoSomething1();
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in your form (and also in your unit test project) you merely use :

```
MyClass _myClass = new MyClass( a, b, c);
_myClass.MyMethod( x, y );
```

Comment: The reason why its in the main form is because the hardware1 2 and 3 classes have to be accessed in the MyMethod function which is only available in the main form

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use NUnit and NSubstitute for unit testing in C#.

You are right when you say that it's way better to test against an interface rather than the actual implementation. 
With NSubstitute you can mock interfaces and set the return value of all methods declared within that interface:

```
//Test
var someType = Substitute.For<ISomeType>();
var someParameter = 42;
var someReturnValue = 1;
someType.SomeMethod(someParameter).Returns(someReturnValue);
var sut = new SomeClass(someType); //sut means system under test
var result = sut.AMethod();
//This would test positive as you set the return value of SomeMethod to 1 
//in case it gets called with a value of 42
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(someReturnValue));
//Test end

//This would be the class you want to unit test
public class SomeClass
{
    private ISomeType someType;

    public SomeClass(ISomeType someType)
    {
        this.someType = someType;
    }

    public int AMethod()
    {
        return someType.SomeMethod(42);
    }
}
```

What happens here is that your test mocks `SomeType` and sets the return value of its method `SomeMethod` to `1` if it gets called with a parameter of `42`.

This way you can easily control which values you get of a mocked service when calling a certain method.

Comment: hey thank you for your answer ! I am currently using Moq for unit testing c# while using MSTest